# Utility of config() in python tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I have this python script, what is the use of `config()` in the python tkinter module?

```
from tkinter import *   
root=Tk()
def sel():
   s=v.get()
   if s=="m":
       l.config(text="CORRECT ANSWER!!!")
   else:
       l.config(text="WRONG ANSWER")
v=StringVar()
a=Label(root,text="Delhi is the capital of India.",bg="wheat",fg="blue")
a.pack()
r1=Radiobutton(root,text="True",variable=v,value="m",command=sel)
r1.pack(anchor=W)
r2=Radiobutton(root,text="False",variable=v,value="n",command=sel)
r2.pack(anchor=W)
l=Label(root,bg="ivory",fg="darkgreen")
l.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you done any basic research, such as reading some documentation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`config` is used to access an object's attributes after its initialisation. For example, here, you define

`l = Label(root, bg="ivory", fg="darkgreen")`

but then you want to set its `text` attribute, so you use `config`:

`l.config(text="Correct answer!")`

That way you can set the text, and modify it during runtime.

Comment: is config the same as configure?

Comment: Can't you also just do something like: l["text"] = "Correct answer!"